# Running executable file from terminal

Tags: command-line, executable

I am new to Ubuntu and currently I am trying to run executable files from the terminal but nothing is happening. When I am listing the files in the current directory I am obtaining the following:

```
brandon@ubuntu:~/Desktop/file_mapping/Debug$ ls -l
total 104
-rwxr-xr-x 1 brandon brandon 88481 Apr 25 19:59 file_mapping
-rw-r--r-- 1 brandon brandon  1001 Apr 26 00:00 makefile
-rw-r--r-- 1 brandon brandon   231 Apr 24 18:58 objects.mk
-rw-r--r-- 1 brandon brandon   392 Apr 26 00:00 sources.mk
drwxr-xr-x 2 brandon brandon  4096 Apr 25 19:59 src
```

However when I am trying to run the `file_mapping` exec file, the following is obtained:

```
brandon@ubuntu:~/Desktop/file_mapping/Debug$ ./file_mapping
open: No such file or directory
```

Comment: is home mounted noexec ?

Comment: use sh <filename>

Comment: @ECarterYoung and what if it is a binary file, not a shell script?

Comment: Are you trying to install or compile something? Just wondering why there is a makefile along with the source code inside of the directory.

Comment: If it can be invoked via sh, its a shell script ./ is shorthand for sh.  For an executable/binary, you just type the name.  Your next thing would be to open `file_mapping` in a text editor, and post the code here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the error you show, you are actually running `file_mapping`. The problem is probably in the executable itself. Note the error:

```
open: No such file or directory
```

`open` is actually a command, I am assuming that `file_mapping` is a script that calls `open` on a non-existent file. I can't be sure of the details unless you post the contents of `file_mapping` though.

In any case, you have successfully ran an executable file from the terminal, your problem is something else.